# VB.NET mailto: Run-time error '91'

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2012, mailto, visual-web-developer

Can anyone take a look at my code below and recommend how I can stop receiving the dreaded error 91. Error: Object variable or With block variable not set. 
I am using the mailto: function to send an email using the native email client and populating the email w/ data from a gridview. After the error pops up, I simply click ok and the email is loaded w/ the exact data I want!

```
Protected Sub GridView2_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles GridView2.SelectedIndexChanged, GridView1.SelectedIndexChanged
    Dim MailFormat, Number, BodyOfEmail, FullName As String
    Dim RowValue As Double

    RowValue = GridView1.SelectedDataKey.Value - 1
    Number = GridView1.Rows(RowValue).Cells(5).Text.ToString
    FullName = GridView1.Rows(RowValue).Cells(25).Text.ToString
    BodyOfEmail = “SomeTextInTheBody”
    MailFormat = "mailto:" & Number & "?" & "subject= A subject here" & "&body=" & BodyOfEmail
    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(MailFormat)
End Sub
```

I can execute the following code from the .aspx page just fine:

```
a href="mailto:someone@example.com?Subject=Hello%20again"
```

and outlook opens without issue. It appears to only be an issue when the aspx.vb code up at the top is executed...

Thanks

Comment: On what line is the error occurring?

Comment: Error is occuring when System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(MailFormat) is executed and occurs inside of outlook. Pop up box is title SCOutlook.

Comment: Tested with sample values and the only thing odd is the declaration of variables with that superfluos comma after FullName, removed and then it works

Comment: I've corrected that typo. That however was not the error I was referring to.

Comment: The weird thing is that if I call: <a href="mailto:someone@example.com?Subject=Hello%20again"> from the .aspx page instead of calling the above code from the aspx.vb page, Outlook opens fine, without the error.

Comment: Is anyone aware of how I could turn the GridView2_SelectedIndexChanged procedure into a script which would be located on the .aspx page? Or how I could take RowValue, number, fullname and BodyOfEmail on the .aspx page?

Comment: @user2312069 no idea why anybody would waste time with this approach.  Process.Start doesn't work in asp.net as it does in windows forms.  Use the smtp class example below or use javascript... or hire a coder.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`<a href="mailto:xxx"/>` works fine because it is executing in the user's browser, and will use the user's locally-installed interactive email application, whatever it happens to be.

`Process.Start("mailto:xxx")` will always fail because it is executing on the web server, which will probably not have a locally-installed interactive email application available, and even if it did, you would not be able to start it interactively on a desktop that does not exist. The fact that it happens to throw error 91 in your test environment is irrelevant. Don't do it, full stop.

What you need to do is arrange for a bit of JavaScript to execute on page render after the server-side event has completed. Something like `location.href = "mailto:xxx"` may do the trick. Exactly where you should insert this depends on your page design.

Alternatively, if you want to keep the email generation code entirely on the server-side, and you know that your users will always be using Outlook, you could look at calling Exchange Server directly. See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/exchange/dd633710.aspx) for a starting point.

Comment: Can anyone provide me some guidance on how I can execute this recommended java script?

Comment: Thanks for providing this understanding to me.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using the [SmtpClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.smtpclient.aspx) class?

```
Dim SmtpServer As New SmtpClient()
Dim mail As New MailMessage()
SmtpServer.Credentials = New Net.NetworkCredential("sender address", "sender password")
SmtpServer.Port = 587              'If sending from gmail...
SmtpServer.Host = "smtp.gmail.com" 'If sending from gmail...
mail = New MailMessage()
mail.From = New MailAddress("sender address")
mail.To.Add("recipient address")
mail.Subject = ""
mail.Body = ""
SmtpServer.Send(mail)
```

Comment: I have but I want the email to launch the user's local outlook client so they have a copy of the sent email in their Sent folder.

Comment: It is a requirement of the client and therefore required. I wouldn't be going down this road if it wasn't a must :).

Comment: Ummm, is there anyway you could add the email manually to the sent folder?

Comment: Why not use SmptClient and just CC the user sending the e-mail, so they have a copy in their Inbox? This meets the requirement of the sender having a copy.

Comment: It's not uncommon in situations like this to send a copy both to the original recipient _and_ the sender - LinkedIn, eBay and many others do this to allow both parties to have a full email record without trying any of this fakery... @HardCode beat me to it by 3 seconds

Comment: The reason why I do not want to explore this is because, I currently am not asking for a the Senders email address. The GridView for which I am harvesting to get values for the body of the email contains the recipients email address. I would need to require the sender to enter an email address somewhere in order to be included on the CC'd list.